# Dialogflow Push notification : Permission not requested to user

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I follow the https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates#push_notifications documentation with API V1.

after returning from my webhook:

```
appAi.askForUpdatePermission('check_overdue_tasks')
```

I get the following message from the simulator:
***Sorry, I didn't get any response.***

What is missing ?

Is it OK with API V1 ?

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARUo...",
  "conversationToken": "CiZDIzVhMz...",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "response": "Sorry, I didn't get any response.",
  "visualResponse": {
    "agentLogoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VTpjRH_pRB4/Wf99LmZh5jI/AAAAAAAAAAg/2HZnqZAsRHcemFxLz5mhsMoP_YQwUVW-ACMYCGAYYCw/h192-w192/logo-ticatag.png",
    "visualElements": []
  }
}
```

DEBUG:

```
{
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {
    "agentToAssistantJson": {
      "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\"]",
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "expectedInputs": [
        {
          "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "simpleResponse": {
                    "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "possibleIntents": [
            {
              "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
              "inputValueData": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                "permissions": [
                  "UPDATE"
                ],
                "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
                  "intent": "check_overdue_tasks",
                  "arguments": [
                    {
                      "name": "taskCategory",
                      "textValue": "home"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "speechBiasingHints": [
            "$object-name",
            "$taskCategory",
            "$object-type"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "responseMetadata": {
        "status": {},
        "queryMatchInfo": {
          "queryMatched": true,
          "intent": "ff669222-3121-4032-acb9-5f3d609cebf1",
          "parameterNames": [
            "taskCategory"
          ]
        }
      },
      "expectedInput": {
        "requestedIntent": {
          "intent": "ff669222-3121-4032-acb9-5f3d609cebf1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {
    "assistantToAgentJson": {
      "user": {
        "userId": "ABwppHF3IIUlbUcuhVS6Vt0csX0D6h1rtRyXb_Fs1FoO2T0RVz3r0tZSsUrupE_WYWO2sLaTwf6fFw",
        "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25JZCI6IkY5RUIzOUNDLTA4OTktNDFBMC05QTU1LTJGOTgyMEYwREU0NCIsImF1ZCI6WyJkZXZpY2VzIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImZ2aXN0aWNvdCt0aWJlQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJpbmdfZGV2aWNlcyIsInJlYWRfZGV2aWNlcyJdLCJsYW5ndWFnZSI6ImZyLUZSIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEyOTc3MzM5LCJ1c2VySWQiOiJCNjJERTEzNC04QzY0LTQ4ODgtOEFENS0yOUM3MDBEOERFRDAiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiMzRkMmUwNjktMjI4MS00Yzg4LWI0ZGQtZDBmZTg2ZDkzOGQyIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZ29vZ2xlLWFjdGlvbiJ9.eIIo-4Yo42V4Apjyj3NOZRIphgRsME06djHbqSVisVpK6gbSZErWDgVHobna1nUTxbjtnVyKqRVVCfshCpa95ghvHImsx-e7f_PCZplSzHdWeylE9BUNWuG1kVXarGRwLkAe7lHLeT5_j2HNoxW4Mo7bwkXYCziDavdEHks4mXBY5cOEtGd7fqYZfDwEclyNDXxnsifl-ZUEJxRWCiSq8ZFXxxJ21aB0gvDdZ1Zuon_oLEese3LeLeYxLyTy0j2badxJrbvr9AOQrHGGBcdvZfujAIWxlszr4V2Ew1BK23LedWOn5HBGD8ahJFrz_1EANR9IgF8dbeDxApxGQNagRQ",
        "locale": "fr-FR",
        "lastSeen": "2017-12-10T20:19:37Z",
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "1513115166506",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"actions_capability_audio_output\",\"actions_capability_screen_output\",\"ff669222-3121-4032-acb9-5f3d609cebf1_id_dialog_context\",\"google_assistant_input_type_keyboard\",\"setup_alerts_dialog_context\",\"setup_alerts_dialog_params_taskcategory\"]"
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
              "query": "home"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "name": "text",
              "rawText": "home",
              "textValue": "home"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=1a22c3f7fd24449480f34f409b2320d0' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImE0ZTgxMmI3MDVjNWUwMjYxZmI4NWQ0ZjAyZDBjZmY1NjkwMjM2NDUifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJ0aWJlLTM4MDQwIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwianRpIjoiMzQzNzk1NTQxZDEwZjFhMjc3ZDM3NWVjZWJiZTVlZThiMTU4MTI5NyIsImlhdCI6MTUxMzExNTE3OCwiZXhwIjoxNTEzMTE1Mjk4LCJuYmYiOjE1MTMxMTQ4Nzh9.PGuWnKB4zNF7zqir_vS26oXyTJ9APL3BBObVsPfqr9oODy_HYrW1wqV49r9ttYgrjea6dTTmj2Z9MsH3LGOxSDHzni2qJaFAewZufnt3ks26_e0b7Tt8qpEXcbeS4zZXg3tENQ4VaS1Rmc5OpZ028F50acJdwWVWTphleUB5XHQOk-3Kg8ts84KtzKjo6HKpe4QSEo6SlWF-AN7Y3XsTbPa3H4nFDTfNB6QFUcv0EdEtr62Q1clmobCePwZzPfp4C8CunRRf8Q-mhiuuF6YcWEww14X9iJIwUCkYulTiCUw7Rrn3legSwf9Y4ppKNx66j7tRxlf6qsDs8Ax0vS2oXw'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHF3IIUlbUcuhVS6Vt0csX0D6h1rtRyXb_Fs1FoO2T0RVz3r0tZSsUrupE_WYWO2sLaTwf6fFw\",\"accessToken\":\"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25JZCI6IkY5RUIzOUNDLTA4OTktNDFBMC05QTU1LTJGOTgyMEYwREU0NCIsImF1ZCI6WyJkZXZpY2VzIl0sInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImZ2aXN0aWNvdCt0aWJlQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJpbmdfZGV2aWNlcyIsInJlYWRfZGV2aWNlcyJdLCJsYW5ndWFnZSI6ImZyLUZSIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEyOTc3MzM5LCJ1c2VySWQiOiJCNjJERTEzNC04QzY0LTQ4ODgtOEFENS0yOUM3MDBEOERFRDAiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiMzRkMmUwNjktMjI4MS00Yzg4LWI0ZGQtZDBmZTg2ZDkzOGQyIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZ29vZ2xlLWFjdGlvbiJ9.eIIo-4Yo42V4Apjyj3NOZRIphgRsME06djHbqSVisVpK6gbSZErWDgVHobna1nUTxbjtnVyKqRVVCfshCpa95ghvHImsx-e7f_PCZplSzHdWeylE9BUNWuG1kVXarGRwLkAe7lHLeT5_j2HNoxW4Mo7bwkXYCziDavdEHks4mXBY5cOEtGd7fqYZfDwEclyNDXxnsifl-ZUEJxRWCiSq8ZFXxxJ21aB0gvDdZ1Zuon_oLEese3LeLeYxLyTy0j2badxJrbvr9AOQrHGGBcdvZfujAIWxlszr4V2Ew1BK23LedWOn5HBGD8ahJFrz_1EANR9IgF8dbeDxApxGQNagRQ\",\"locale\":\"fr-FR\",\"lastSeen\":\"2017-12-10T20:19:37Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{}}\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1513115166506\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"_actions_on_google_\\\",\\\"actions_capability_audio_output\\\",\\\"actions_capability_screen_output\\\",\\\"ff669222-3121-4032-acb9-5f3d609cebf1_id_dialog_context\\\",\\\"google_assistant_input_type_keyboard\\\",\\\"setup_alerts_dialog_context\\\",\\\"setup_alerts_dialog_params_taskcategory\\\"]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"home\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"home\",\"textValue\":\"home\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
  },
  "sharedDebugInfo": [
    {
      "debugInfo": "Empty TTS.",
      "name": "Tts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the output in the "Request", "Response", and "Debug" tabs from the simulator?

Comment: Question updated with debug info

Comment: @prisoner any idea, I really need help !!!

Comment: @fvisticot try into real device.

Comment: Does not work either on real evice